# Jordan normal form 33

Tags: jordan-normal-form

what is the Jordan normal form for matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3&1& 0\\0& 3& 0\\0& 0& 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

can't figure out because some eigenvalues makes some rows 0

and how can I find solution for this equation x′=Ax

Comment: Isnt' this matrix already in Jordan normal form??

Comment: The matrix is already in Jordan normal form.

Comment: Wolfram is writing that it is not

Comment: Wolfram is, again, high: that's the JNF of that matrix., with eigenvalues $\;3\;$ of algebraic mult. two and geometric mult. one, and the eigenvalue two, of alg. and geom. multiplicity one

Comment: how than I can find x′=Ax

Comment: x′=Ax A = \begin{pmatrix}
3&1&0\\
0&3&0\\
0&0&2
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan+form+of+%5B%5B3,1,0%5D,%5B+0,3,0%5D,+%5B0,0,1%5D%5D) seems to want the eigenvalues in increasing order.  There are various conventions, but ordinarily your matrix does qualify as a Jordan normal form.

Comment: The [matrix exponential](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Matrix+exponential+of+t*%5B%5B3,1,0%5D,%5B+0,3,0%5D,+%5B0,0,1%5D%5D) is
$$ \pmatrix{e^{3t} & t e^{3t} & 0\cr 0 & e^{3t} & 0\cr 0 & 0 & e^{2t}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solutions  of $x'=Ax$ write 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3&1& 0\\0& 3& 0\\0& 0& 2
\end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 3&0& 0\\0& 3& 0\\0& 0& 2
\end{bmatrix}}_D+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 0&1& 0\\0& 0& 0\\0& 0&
\end{bmatrix}}_N$$
$D$ and $N$ commute (I insist) so that $\;\exp(At)=\exp(Dt)\cdot\exp(Nt)$. As $N^2=0$, $\exp(Nt)=I+Nt$ and
$$\exp(At)=\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm e^{3t}&0& 0\\0&  \mathrm e^{3t}& 0\\0& 0& \mathrm e^{2t}
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1&t& 0\\0&  1& 0\\0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm e^{3t}&t\mathrm e^{3t}& 0\\0&  \mathrm e^{3t}& 0\\0& 0& \mathrm e^{2t}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: so D and N are what?

Comment: The diagonal part and the nilpotent part of $A$, as shown in the first equation line.

Comment: but I need to find x′=Ax

Comment: As I explained, the solution is $x(t)=\exp(At)=\exp(Dt)\exp(Nt)$ since $At=(D+N)t=Dt+Nt$, and $D$ and $N$ commute.

Comment: is there a equation form of representation?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. A formula like $x(t)=\dots, y(t)=\dots, z(t)=\dots$?

Comment: X(t)=c1e−tv1+c2etv2+c3et(v2t+v3) like that(it is just an example)

Comment: $X(t)=c1e^(−t)v1+c2e^tv2+c3e^t(v2t+v3)$

Comment: Your formula is not really readable.

Comment: Solve the homogeneous equation x′ = Ax
to find n linearly independent vector solutions x1, x2, . . . , xn, and hence the homogeneous solution xh = c1x1 +c2x2 +···+cnx

Comment: The $3$ linearly independent solutions are the column vectors of $\exp(At)$. This is expressed in a synthetic way with the formula $\;x(t)=\exp(At)x(0)$.

Comment: how than I can rewrite that it looks like this formula?

Comment: Multiply the matrix $\exp(At)$ by a column vector $\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: do I need also to multiply $P*(exp(Dt)*exp(Nt))*P^-1$ ?

Comment: In relation to your previous post? Yes, of course. Do it before multiplying by the column vector.

Comment: Yesterday you have asked 5 questions ! Take time to breath. Usually 1 question per day is enough, sometimes 2 questions, very exceptionally 3 questions. More means that it becomes a reflex to ask for an answer without searching in a thorough way.

Answer (score 0):

THis matrix is in [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) with a first Jordan block
$$J_1=\begin{bmatrix}
3&1\\0&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that means that the matrix has an eigenvalue $\lambda_1=3$ with algebraic multiplicity $2$ and geometric multiplicity $1$.

And a second Jordan block $J_2=2$ that means that the other eigenvalue is $\lambda_2=2$ ( with algebraic and geometric multiplicity $=1$).

Note that the Jordan normal form of a matrix is not unique because we can put the Jordan blocks in different order.